# GridBagLayout staggered buttons

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

How do I get the columns for GridBagLayout to be spaced out evenly so that I can place buttons like they are on a standard staggered computer keyboard? I'm talking about something like this, where the buttons don't quite line up with each other: [image: QWERTY Keyboard]

Minimal functional working example (notice the staggered `gridx` and `gridwidth` values):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Keyboard extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Keyboard()).setVisible(true);
    }

    public Keyboard() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 300);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton[] b = new JButton[5];
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

        b[0] = new JButton("A");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(b[0], c);

        b[1] = new JButton("B");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(b[1], c);

        b[2] = new JButton("C");
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(b[2], c);

        b[3] = new JButton("D");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(b[3], c);

        b[4] = new JButton("E");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(b[4], c);
    }
}
```

I want the right border of button D to go all the way to halfway in between A and B, while E should be between B and C. How do I do this?

Comment: Compound panels, `Insets` and `Border`s

Comment: In addition to multiple panels for different groups of button, maybe a BoxLayout will help since you can add "struts" which is basically an invisible component that will allow you shift components on alternate rows.

Comment: GridBagLayout probably isn't a good choice, since `new JButton("I")` and `new JButton("W")` will not have the same width, even if they have the same gridwidth and weightx in the layout.  So yes, you should use multiple panels, and you should use a layout that forces components to have widths proportional to each other.  GridLayout could do the "standard size" keys, but not the others, so you'll probably need SpringLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered adding in a dummy item to the begining of the second row that has its opacity set to 0? Just set it's width to the exact tabbing you need.